# asp.net Syntax [] instead of ()

Tags: c#, asp.net, syntax

Can some one explain why brackets are used instead of () in the single line of code below (c# codeBehind ASP.NET), and provide the technical document reference for this syntax

```
string cssFile = Request.Cookies["InquiryId"].Value;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `[]` syntax that you are looking at is called the [Indexers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx)(msdn link).

Comment: "Indexers allow instances of a class or struct to be indexed just like arrays."  This is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 4):

You may take a look at [indexed properties](http://en.csharp-online.net/Create_an_indexer_property). That's what is defined for the Cookies property.

Answer (score 3):

its a c# rather than VB.Net convention for accessing an array, nothing to do with asp.net really, rather the language choice for the code behind

Answer (score 1):

Because Cookies is some kind of dictionary. Or more general: It defines an indexer property. Therefor the [] have to be used. () are used for a method call, which is just something different.